# react native error fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Hello I am getting these error after installing react native-naviation component
I am using EXPO for instead of NVD. More important is to resolve bold warning(last two warning)

```
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react-native@3.2.1 requires a peer of eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN native-base@2.7.2 requires a peer of react@>=16.4.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN native-base@2.7.2 requires a peer of react-native@>=0.56.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-maps@0.21.0 requires a peer of react-native@^0.51 || ^0.52 || ^0.53 || ^0.54 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN react-native-reanimated@1.0.0-alpha.3 requires a peer of react@16.0.0-alpha.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN react-native-reanimated@1.0.0-alpha.3 requires a peer of react-native@^0.44.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

**npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):**

**npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})**
```

Comment: Seems like your dependencies are outdated. You should type `npm outdated` and update all of the red ones.

Answer (score 0):

None of these errors are anything to worry about. Infact, they are not errors but a warnings.

eslint code quality checking software. It simply checks your code to see if it is adhering to the best standards. You could turn off that warning if you wished.

fsevents is an optional dependency. This error comes up (usually) if you are using npm on mac systems. It should have no effect on your build though. If you're particularly upset about those last two errors, run `npm i -f` to force a fetch of remote resources (which should get rid of that dependency issue).